# Google analytics not working iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, google-analytics

I have implemented 3 steps.

**Step 1:** I have Downloaded google analytics Library files and added this files to project,

- GAI.h
- GAITrackedViewController.h
- GAITracker.h
- GAITransaction.h
- GAITransactionItem.h
- libGoogleAnalytics.a
- CoreData.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework

**Step 2:** Added this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

   [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;

    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 2;
    [GAI sharedInstance].debug=YES;
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-1"];

    return YES;
}
```

**Step 3:** In my `HomeScreen` view which loads after launch image
i wrote this,
I have updated this header to:

```
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface BTSHomeViewController : GAITrackedViewController
```

and in `BTSHomeViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    ...
     self.trackedViewName = @"Home";
}
```

***Note:*** I have wrote`self.trackedViewName = @"Home";` only on firstpage not in all the Pages it is necessary to write in all pages ?

also LOG shows this warning:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Supriya/Desktop/BTS with Analytics/BTS 2.1/BTS/BTS/GoogleAnalytics/Library'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Supriya/Desktop/BTS with Analytics/BTS 2.1/BTS/../../Documents'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Supriya/Desktop/BTS with Analytics/BTS 2.1/BTS/../../../Documents'
```

After writing this when i run my code in Device, google analytics doesn't show any active users.

Here is the snapshot of my framework folder in my project, am i forgetting adding any library ?

[image]:
**Please help, what is the mistake ?**

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: Have you created a GA account and changed the tracking ID ?

Comment: No need to ask same question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/18585583/1603072) multiple times. You can always edit the question.

Comment: I have standard Google account, i have tried one simple project with same above steps it works fine but when i try to follow same steps in my apps it is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just to confirm, but you have used a tracking ID for a mobile app right? A tracking ID created for a web application will not give you anything when used in a mobile app.
2. Once the initial set-up is done in App Delegate, tracking can just as easily be done with something like this - `[[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] trackView:@"Screen name"];`

Comment: Where do you get the tracker id for a mobile app, all I see is one tracker id when I log onto my google analytics account

Comment: When you create a new tracking code, you are asked if it is for a mobile application.

Comment: How to create a new tracking code on the same account? I don't see a way

Answer (score 1):

According to the google documentation you should set `trackedviewname` in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

To be sure that your ID is correct you should try to test analytics without the automatic screen measurement and using `[[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] sendView:page]`;